# Error C2064 — I don't know what I did wrong

Tags: c++

I need help with this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;

int possibleOres;//int für die möglichen Erze

vector<string>::iterator Ore; //Iterator um das Ore auszuwählen
vector<string>::iterator Iter; //iterator deklariert
for(Iter = OreList.begin(); Iter != OreList.end(); Iter++)
{
    possibleOres++;
}
cout << "There are " (possibleOres) <<" possible Ores."; //this part does not work
```

I searched with Google already, and searched this site, but I didn't find an answer I could use. I have a vector with different Ores in it and I try to count and display it. I tried this kind of code in another program and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: You're missing a `<<` between `"There are"` and `(possibleOres)`

Comment: You're missing a `<<` in the line `cout << "There are " (possibleOres) <<` (before the `(`).

Comment: When you ask a question about an error message, please include the error message in the question.  Not everyone has your particular compiler, but many people will be able to interpret the error message if you show it (and it is often easier to interpret the message than to scan the code to find the cause).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cout << "There are " (possibleOres) <<" possible Ores."
```

You're missing a "<<" before (possibleOres).  As a result, the compiler thinks `"There are "` is a function you're trying to invoke.  Hence the error message "term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 argument".